# Jquery - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined

Tags: jquery, scroll, error-handling

I've seen lots of entries with this title but none that helped my specific problem. I don't know what the problem could be. I followed a youtube tutorial and did exactly what they did. But when I click on my anchor link, nothing happens and I get this error in the console: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined.

This is my Javascript:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $("a").click(function() {
            if(this.hash) {
                var hash = this.hash.substr(1);

                var $toElement = $("a[name="+hash+"]");
                var toPosition = $toElement.position().top;

                $("body,html").animate({
                    scrollTop : toPosition
                },2000,"easeOutExpo");
                return false;
            } 
        });
    });
</script>
```

[Jsfiddle with my full code](https://jsfiddle.net/1ck5quk3/)

Comment: `$("a[name='"+hash+"']");` change to this.

Comment: your target element does not have a name attribute.

Comment: Now I get: Uncaught TypeError: jQuery.easing[this.easing] is not a function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Top of undefined* 
 error occurs because of accessing 'top' style of an element that is not defined. 
here change

```
var $toElement = $("a[name="+hash+"]");
```

To

```
var $toElement = $("a[href=#"+hash+"]");
```

Hope it will solve your problem

Answer (score 3):

The issue is your target element doesnot have a name attribute:

```
<a href="#about_me" id="scroll_down">About Me</a>
```

As you can see above there is no name attribute, Either you add it

```
<a href="#about_me" name="about_me" id="scroll_down">About Me</a>
<!------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^-----add this----->
```

or change the `href` to `name` and remove the `#`:

```
<a name="about_me" id="scroll_down">About Me</a>
<!-^^^^^^^^^^^^^^-----change href to name----->
```

#### [Updated Fiddle with easings.](https://jsfiddle.net/1ck5quk3/2/)

In the fiddle you have to use easing code as the easing you are using is not available in the jQuery, so [you have to put the code/library](http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/jquery.easing.1.3.js).

Comment: Now I get: Uncaught TypeError: jQuery.easing[this.easing] is not a function

Comment: @Mattlee https://jsfiddle.net/1ck5quk3/2/ check this updated fiddle. You need to have that easing code in your file or just make a reference to the file.

Comment: I had to copy it all directly into the html to make it work. It wouldn't work if I just linked it on a separate page. Anyway, I did it and it didn't do exactly what I want. It stops at the a element with the id="scroll_down". I want it to stop with the top of the about_me div at the top of the browser.

Comment: Okay I got it to work the way I wanted. I still wish I didn't have to paste the entire easing code into my html. I have to do that AND link it in a separate file. Or else it doesn't work.

Comment: @MattLee can you show how you are adding your easing file in the page? My suggestion is add this file before your script and below the jQuery library.

Comment: I tried just copying all the easing code to a .js file and calling it easing.js and then linking it in with 

<script type="text/javascript src="js/easing.js"></script> 

but that doesn't work. I have to do all that plus paste all the easing code into my head tags. Which makes the file really really long. If I delete either one of those things from the html it doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Your answers helped me come to a solution. I was trying to make it scroll to a div. Not an href or an a tag. I finally got it in order and it scrolls to the right places and it works for all the buttons on my site now. Thanks, all who helped me come to this.